# Android : How to change a recurring event to one time event programatically

Tags: android, android-calendar

Hi I am Using Calendar Contract APIs and only supports the API level 14 and above so I do not care about older version support.

I am stuck with a problem while updating a recurrence event to a single time occurrence event.
I cant' give `Events.DTEND` values while updating the event as an error shows as `Events.DURATION` and `Events.DTEND` can't be present at same time.

I am not passing `Events.DURATION` but Android  didn't allow to update the event, but if I pass `Events.DURATION` as empty like `deviceCalendarValues.put(Events.DURATION, "");` along with the correct value for `Events.DTEND`. This leads to more complicated situation like two event will be added one will take duration as zero and make the start and end time same. Other event will be present with the given data for from time and to time and after the syncing of calendar (I added event to the google calendar its listed along with other available calendars) the event with correct data will be deleted and the wrong event will be exist there.

One more thing I am updating on `Events.CONTENT_URI` like

```
updateUri = ContentUris.withAppendedId(Events.CONTENT_URI, event_dao.getI_EventID());

updatedRowCount = activity.getContentResolver().update(updateUri,
            deviceCalendarValues, null, null);
```

What is going wrong here? What is the right way to change a repeating event to a single occurrence event?

Answer (score 0):

```
    ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
    if(this.id>0)
        values.put(Events._ID, this.id);

    values.put(Events.DTSTART, this.startMillis);
    if(title!=null)
        values.put(Events.TITLE, title.toString());
    if(description!=null)
        values.put(Events.DESCRIPTION,  description.toString());

    values.put(Events.CALENDAR_ID, SharedPreferenceManager.getSharedInstance().getCalendarId());

    values.put(Events.EVENT_TIMEZONE, TimeZone.getDefault().getID());

    if(location!=null)
        values.put(Events.EVENT_LOCATION,  location.toString());
    values.put(Events.ALL_DAY, allDay ? 1 : 0);

 if(!TextUtils.isEmpty(rule)) { 
        values.put(Events.RRULE, rule);
        values.put(Events.DURATION, getDuration());
        values.put(Events.DTEND, (Long) null);
    }else {
        values.put(Events.DTEND, endMillis);
}

    values.put(Events.ACCESS_LEVEL, 0);// Default (0), Private (2), Public (3)
    values.put(Events.EVENT_COLOR_KEY, AppUtility.getColorKeyFromColorCode(color));
```

TEND should be passed as null if it is recurring event